# Button value sets a request attribute

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

Is it possible to do smth like this:

```
<button type="submit" name="Remove" value=<% request.setAttribute("status", "removed")%> >Remove</button><br />
```

Will the button **value** workout this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't work that way. Java/JSP runs in the webserver and generates HTML which the webserver sends to webbrowser. Rightclick page in webbrowser and do *View Source*. You see, there's no single line of Java/JSP code.

The `value` attribute should represent the button's value which is to be sent as request parameter value. If you actually want to check in the next view (as definied in `<form action>` URL of the form associated with this button), then you should just check the presence of the button's `name` in the request parameter map.

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.Remove}">
    You pressed the Remove button!
</c:if>
```

*(here `Remove` is the `name` of the button, I'd rather lowercase it by the way)*

Alternatively, you can set the attribute in the servlet which the form is submitting to:

```
if (request.getParameter("Remove") != null) {
    request.setAttribute("status", "removed");
}
```

and then check it in the forwarded JSP as follows:

```
<c:if test="${status == 'removed'}">
    You pressed the Remove button!
</c:if>
```

Comment: thank you very much) I promise, i'll get better and won't ask such stupid questions)